# How can I make this menu responsive to resolution 13``?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I used this tool

http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//reliancetrustgroup.com/&w=1280&h=800&a=1

If you test this site you'll see that the resolution 13`` (the smallest of both) my menu in Spanish is not responsive.

This is code for the menu:

```
    #site-navigation
{
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

How do I change the menu so it looks good for smaller resolutions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is resolution 13?

Comment: I mean device size  13`` = 1280x800

Comment: If you have a size in pixels, 13" says nothing. 1280x800 is what you are working with, regardless of screen size.

Comment: and then you should only change the width and be in px be the percentage?